# Using DateDiff in Access to colour code dates in Conditional Formatting

Tags: ms-access, vba, datediff, conditional-formatting

I have a table of clearances and their expiry dates. If a clearance has expired I would like it to be red, if it expires within 6 months I want it to be amber, if it expires in more than 6 months green and if it is yet to be granted (hence doesn't yet have an expiry date) then black.

I have got the text to default as black and then have

RED

```
[C_ExpiryDate]<Now()
```

AMBER

```
DateDiff("m",[C_ExpiryDate],Now())<6 And [C_ExpiryDate]>Now()
```

GREEN

```
DateDiff("m",[C_ExpiryDate],Now())>6 And [C_ExpiryDate]>Now()
```

This seems to have a few different problems, the red works fine from what I can tell. But the other two seem to be handled poorly, for example a clearance with 06 Sep 2015 is amber (today is 03 July 2014 so this should be green). Similar for 05 Mar 2017, I think it is just looking at the month regardless of the year, but I'm not too sure how to handle this better.

Not sure if it might be easier to default as green and perhaps write something like

```
[C_ExpiryDate] = ""
```

But this didn't seem to do anything and everything was coming up as green even when there was a blank date. Similar for single quotations.

Any suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of MS Access are you using? This works for me:

[image: conditional formatting]

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, hadn't thought of using DateAdd but I like it. I'm using 2010 and only thing is that the amber condition is just Value Between rather than Value Is Between

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it written this is happening (i'm substituting `#06/Sept/2015#` for `[C_ExpiryDate]` to keep with your example)

Red?

```
#06/Sept/2015#<Now() --> False
```

Amber?

```
DateDiff("m",#06/Sept/2015#,Now())<6 And #06/Sept/2015#>Now() --> True
```

Green is not evaluated

The problem is that you have the greater date first and the lesser date last. Switch them.

Or alternatively, since you are checking `[C_ExpiryDate]>Now()` anyway you can take the absolute value of them and not worry about order.

```
#06/Sept/2015# < Now() --> False (Red)
DateDiff("m",Now(),#06/Sept/2015#) < 6 And #06/Sept/2015# > Now() --> False (Amber)
DateDiff("m",Now(),#06/Sept/2015#) > 6 And #06/Sept/2015# > Now() --> True (Green)
```

You have no `equal to 6 months` condition though. Something for you to think about.

Comment: Not to mention that date is never equal to a string.

Comment: I prefer dateadd, but +1  :)

Comment: Thanks, I imagine this would work too, but I quite like the DateAdd function (and I read the above comment first) so I've used that.